# Getting an error with the configuration of task ';checkDebugManifest'

Tags: java, android, spring, gradle

I am building my first android project with Gradle with the help of [Spring Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/gradle-android/). When I run `gradle build`, I get the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':checkDebugManifest'.
> File 'C:\Windows\System32\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml' specified for property 'manifest' does not
 exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more l
og output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Here is the AndroidManifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.hello"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0.0" >

<application android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".HelloActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: So, show us the `AndroidMinfest.xml` (or the relevant part of it) and we have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are running Gradle from `C:\Windows\System32` folder. I am not sure if you put your `build.gradle` there too. You need to think about where is your project located and run Gradle there to give it proper context.

Comment: I have two gradle files ‘C:\Windows\System32\build.gradle’ and ‘app\build.gradle’

Comment: There's no need to put `build.gradle` under ` ‘C:\Windows\System32\build.gradle`. You should keep it with project files.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue.  Make sure your manifest is in the correct directory.  I had mistakenly put it in src instead of src/main.  That fixed the issue.